# How do I use/sync my Ubuntu One contacts?

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-one, sync, evolution, contacts

I have added a lot of contacts through my mobile phone and I have never used ubuntu one before for the desktop. I've set up all the preferences in Ubuntu One but it keeps saying "syncing" all the time without any progress. I can't see the contacts in Evolution, where are the files stored? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remember that the initial sync is slow (it's getting better in Natty). The syncing will also appear if you have files being synced. The synced contact are located at `~/.local/share/desktop-couch/couchdb.html` (the ~ is your home folder).

The exact reason for this issue can't be found without some debugging:

1. Open Applications->Accessories->Terminal, and run:

   > /usr/lib/evolution/e-addressbook-factory > ~/evolution_debug.log
2. Open Evolution, check that the status of synced contacts and then close the application.
3. Paste the content of evolution_debug.log (it's in your home folder) to [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/)

It's also a good idea if the contacts have actually been synced to the server from your phone, if they aren't, then they won't obviously appear in Evolution. Can you see the contacts in [Ubuntu One's website](https://one.ubuntu.com/contacts)?

Comment: yes I can see them on the ubuntu one website. I can't really look into this more right now since I dont have an ubuntu system at hand. But I will settle for this answer :) thank you very much!